# What's a "chord register"?

Tags: guitar, theory, chords, terminology

Someone said:

> "When you're doing more than one person who does the rhythm part, do
>   your chord in another register, maybe higher or maybe lower."

What's really the definition of the "register" on "chord register" and what makes the rhythm part become different/more complex?

Comment: It's part of the general rule - don't double up on what someone else is doing. Keep out of the other guy's way. No-one said "chord register", so don't waste time trying to analyse it!

Comment: "Register" has almost the same meaning as "octave." In other words, play the same chords an octave higher or lower to avoid clashing with the lead part!

Comment: On that note, I don't think "chord register" is a thing. The sentence you're quoting uses "chord" and "register" as two different ideas that are related to each other instead of one idea put together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A register in the context in music is very close to and can be thought of as a different way of talking about the range of an instrument, group of notes, ect.  The definition of it is as follows:

> In music, a register is the relative "height" or range of a note, set
>   of pitches or pitch classes, melody, part, instrument, or group of
>   instruments. A higher register indicates higher pitch. - [Wikipieda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28music%29)

In the context of guitar and play chords it makes sense if you had two guitarist playing different voicings/shapes of the same chord to fill out the sound for a thicker texture. For example, if one guitarist is playing an open chord which would be in the lower register for a guitar the other guitarist can play up the voicing/shape up the neck to play in a higher register.

Let's look at a practical example. If someone instructed you to play an E chord, there are many ways to do it and just considering the 5 basic chord shapes we could play an E chord the following ways:

```
%0/.2/.2/.1/.0/.0/[E]
%X/.X/.2/.4/.5/.4/[E]
%X/.7/.6/.4/.5/.4/[E]
%X/.7/.9/.9/.9/.7/[E]
%12/.11/.9/.9/.9/.12/[E]
```

As you can see these are all E chords, but the are all a different set of notes and are all in a slightly different register. Have two guitarist play two different chord shapes produces a much fuller sound than the two playing the exact same notes.

Answer (score 2):

There is little point in two guitarists playing exactly the same chord shape,unless  the rhythm or tones are different. It's to do with the VOICING of chords. If, for example, one player uses an open C( at the head end of the guitar), then it increases the sound for another to play a barre C at the 8th fret. This means that some same notes are played by both, albeit with perhaps a different tone, but extra notes are included. They're all, E and G, but in different octaves, adding a bigger sonic dimension.

Answer (score 0):

An other view, augmenting what was already said and illustrated.

Talking about „registers“ makes a lot of sense for an organ. If you look at an old one in a church, switching registers simply means switching set of pipes.

Pipes can sound like flutes, like trumpets or horns and so on. Some sound loud as a mighty thunder, some silent, and each set has a different sound characteristic, i.e. frequency spectrum. Not all will be in harmony with other „instruments“, like the choir or the singing community.

So changing register here means also adapting to the musical situation. Which, for an electric guitar, could be as simple as turning off an effect, switching to a less disturbing one or lowering the volume.

Was said already, viewed from perhaps its historical origin.

Answer (score -1):

Register is a way of identifying octaves. From C to B the chromatic scale identifies an area of the piano. The guitar starts with E2 and a 22 fret guitar ends with D6. The register starts with C1 to B1 then goes C2-B2, etc.
Two groups of five chromatic pitches are duplicated 5 times. Some pitches are not duplicated some only two, three or four times.

Comment: A register isn't defined absolutely by octave numbering, not to my knowledge. Commonly, a register is just an inexact distinct-sounding region of the frequency spectrum *(I have heard non-musicians misuse "octave" for what musicians call a "register", though)*. Sometimes "register" for an instrument/voice is used more precisely to describe the range of tones created through a specific technique or mechanism, like a saxophone's altissimo register. If you have some information to support the idea that a register starts at C and ends at B as you describe, I'd be interested in reading that.

Comment: I think it's more the other way around.  Octaves can be used to describe the register.  Think of an analogy where register = height, octave = meter.  Saying the first octave is the first register is like saying the first meter is the first height.  But you could say the height is in the 1-2m range (the register is in the 1st octave).  There's probably a better analogy, but that's what I've got.